# Modify a value in another spreadsheet by modifying a form

Tags: forms, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a form that i've received ALOT of help on so far and its almost there, the only thing I need it to do now is a way to adjust "Perks" and in turn made adjustments to the value on the spreadsheet that those perks came from for the specific character selected.  My spreadsheet link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1msXEdUvR2mH1sFPeAdwk8dEdpyVwvBQbEDzXnBb5J8k/edit?usp=sharing and the form is on the copy of bloodweb purchases tab.  Any help would be amazing as all this has been to put it lightly way above anything ive ever done.

Comment: Please be specific where (the destination) and what (the expected output).

Comment: So i have a box with a bunch of level3/2/1/0 perks respectively displayed im looking for a way to modify by incrementing/decrementing the values based on the character selected in e5.  so the character name references either a character name in Survivors or Killers and the perks are all references to perks in those respected spreadsheets as well.  So if i increment a perk in my level 2 perks box id like that cell referenced to increment in whatever spreadsheet it is from.  I dont know if there's a better way to explain it but thats probably the best way i can.

Comment: Please provide a set of sample input and output with screenshots.

Comment: I think `E5`, `E8` and `B9:H24` are working as expected? Where are you talking about?

Comment: Well thats the thing i have no idea how I could do an input that just increases/decreases but for instance you're looking at the level 1 perks for michael.  say I wanted to increase the perk dying light in the box in b9:h24 so id need a way of incrementing dying light which would increase the number in the killers spreadsheet in cell H23.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a circular reference, you have to do the things outside the green area.

1. leave `Column L` of `Bloodweb Purchases` blank and let the user to input the level there
2. refer to `Column L` from `Survivors` and `Killers`

But in order to have a good player experience, I suggest you to make a sidebar with Google Apps Script.

You can then show only the relevant skills instead of all (including skills irrelevant to the current character or level)

Comment: could i just make a plus/minus buton and have i do that way?

Comment: Yes, you can add a drop down list at for example `B26` having list of values in `B9:H24` for the player to select the skill. And add plus and minus buttons next to it.

Comment: Im trying to think if there's another way, I thought about putting an alternating list of drop down boxes in the square for example starting in c9 to c24 and then going to e9...etc but this leaves a column for perks but not enough for another column of drop down boxes.  Plus if i did that there would have to be like a submit button or something to modify the perk then clear the drop down boxes otherwise it would add indefinitely.  I mean your idea is definitely way easier, i made a small attempt at making buttons yesterday but I found I really suck at it lol